# Some Emails Not Pushed to Gmail App

Tags: gmail, exchange, outlook, imap

I have 2 accounts within Outlook 2007 - work email through Microsoft Exchange and a Gmail IMAP account. I have a rule set where email sent to the work account will also be copied to the Inbox of the IMAP account. On my phone (Galaxy S3) I have two Google/Gmail accounts set up - personal email (let's call it G-X) and the one that gets a copy of my work email (let's call it G-Y).

Up until a few days ago I had no problems with receiving emails and notifications on the phone for either Gmail account. Now now if an email is sent directly to G-Y, I am notified through the Gmail app on the phone that I have new mail, but if an email is sent to the work account, where it gets copied to the Gmail IMAP in Outlook, there is no notification, even though the message is displayed as unread/new both in Outlook and gmail.com.

Can anyone shed light on this? I want to be able to get notified when new work email comes to (gets copied to) the Gmail account set up for it.

Answer (score 0):

They are most likely there, just you aren't looking in the right label.
Outlook screws up your GMail folders/labels and causes very annoying GMail sync issues. That's why i quit using outlook with my gmail.

Comment: Could you recommend where to look? Saying that Outook caused your problem so you quit using it doesn't really help @BinaryRock.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem and have been seeing similar issues over the past month or so.

It appears that IMAP copy into Inbox or other Gmail labels no longer generates new mail events / notifications.

I have tested with multiple folders (including the Inbox) using both Outlook 2010 and the latest versions of Thunderbird setup for IMAP. I've found that Android's Gmail app as well as Gooogle's Gmail web interface only update / generate notifications when an email is received by the Gmail servers.

Based on the above, the only conclusion I can come to is that Google is no longer generating new mail events within the overall Gmail environment when an IMAP email client copies messages into folders.  I too wish they would. I was using Outlook to copy email from an Exchange account to a Gmail label and received notification on my Android device. This worked well for a long time (a few years?).

---

Edit: May 1st, 2013

Since my post in March it appears that these notifications are now working. Has been for a couple of weeks. Seems like the problems were most likely issues with Google servers.

Anyway ... I no longer have this problem.